# How to get Rglpk_solve_LP to skip to the next line of code when it is taking too long to complete the calculation?

Tags: r, glpk

I am running simulations in R using R Studio. I need to get an optimal solution using `Rglpk` library. I call repeatedly the function `Rglpk_solve_LP` to solve the problem. At times it works fine but at times it runs forever. I want to be able to skip to next line when `Rglpk_solve_LP` can't converge.

I have attempted to change some of the settings in the `Rglpk_solve_LP` function such as `control = list(lp_time_limit = time_limit )` but it still gets stuck

#### R code

```
lp = Rglpk_solve_LP(obj = obj, mat = mat, dir = dir, 
                    rhs = rhs, max = max, types = rep("B",length(obj)), 
                    control = list(lp_time_limit = 5 ))
print(lp)
lp$solution = lp$solution  
lp$objval = lp$optimum
return (lp)
```

I expect a binary vector indicating whether a particular item was included in the solution. However, in some instances it does not finish the calculation and carries on forever.

Answer (score 0):

The tm_limit should be within double quotes. For example,

```
control = list("tm_limit"=60000)
```

This worked for me, I hope it helps.